# Android Material Themes/Colors: ListView, cursors

Tags: android, android-listview, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, material-design

With the introduction of `Lollipop` and Material Design it has become easier to customize the color pallete of an app through setting the Theme style items `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, `colorAccent`, etc...
However, as far as I see this doesn't cover `ListView` (selector and overscroll glow) and text selection cursor and probably some others areas. This seems like a major omission.

What is currently the best approach to customize all these areas that `colorPrimary`, `colorPrimaryDark`, `colorAccent` seem to miss? (In a centralized way, without generating all the themes and colors like we had to do before the goodies introduced in Lollipop were available)

Edit: I'm interested in these material features running on Android 4.0.3+, not just on Lollipop.

Comment: The `ListView` overscroll seems to match `colorPrimary`, and the activated state uses `colorAccent`, at least in my tests.

Comment: No. There is no `colorPrimary` or `colorAccent` on KitKat.  `Theme.AppCompat` offers a limited backport of this tinting, but it does not cover the things you request. You are welcome to attempt to fork `appcompat-v7` and add this stuff in.

Comment: Sad, it makes this whole colorPrimary/colorAccent thing useless, for now, if we still need to generate everything that it misses ourselves anyways, as before. Thanks :)

Comment: Not all that many apps went and did the whole "generating all the themes and colors" stuff in the first place, settling for whatever the stock theme gives them. For them, `colorPrimary` and kin are perfect, as all they need to do is inherit from `Theme.Material` on Android 5.0, and they get everything tinted. If you are trying to use `appcompat-v7`, you do not get that simplicity.